# powershell find string in csv get associated cell

Tags: powershell

Alright I have a csv that i import into variable $csv

```
name  description  system redundant
----  -----------  ------ ---------
hi    don't settle sight  dumb     
hello why not      settle settle   
this  just fails   why?   settle
```

I want to find a specific string in either $csv.description or $csv.system. If that string is found, i want to return the associated cell value under $csv.name

I can't have the select-string look for anything in $csv.redundant

this is what i have so far:

```
$csv = import-csv -path c:\hi 
$find = $csv | select-string "settle"
```

output: $find

```
@{name=hi; description=don't settle; system=sight; redundant=dumb }
@{name=hello; description=why not; system=settle; redundant=settle}
@{name=this; description=just fails; system=why?; redundant=settle}
```

however - nothing returns if i do a $find.name, even though the $find.gettype() shows that this is an array. Also i don't know how to get the select-string to avoid $csv.redundant

I need the output to only be the $find.name of only the first 2 objects from the array.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Select-String`, use `Where-Object` instead:

```
$searchTerm = 'settle'
$csv |Where-Object {$_.description -match $searchTerm -or $_.system -match $searchTerm} |Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Comment: Wanting to comment here you should start the habit of piping your variables into `Get-Member` to explore what is returned. In the case of  `Import-CSV`, you'll note you get `NoteProperty` for the named column headers. Then you search online for PowerShell filtering on `NoteProperty` Keeping to the theme of powershell, you can pipe those into additional cmdlets or functions...

Comment: Cool - that works. But i have a question. If using select-string keeps it in an array - why can't i select-object $_.name?

Comment: I think it's an array of strings, not an  array of custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
ipcsv C:\temp\test.csv | ? {$_.description, $_.system -like "*settle*"} | select Name
```